# Insert data into nested table

Tags: oracle, reference, insert, nested-table, object-relational-model

May I please have some help to Insert values into a table. The table is called PurchaseOrder_objtab. Here is the type for the table:

```
CREATE TYPE PurchaseOrder_objtyp AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS OBJECT
(
  PONo NUMBER,
  CUST_ref REF Customer_objtyp,
  OrderDate DATE,
  ShipDate DATE,
  LineItemList_ntab LineItemList_ntabtyp,
  ShipToAddr_obj Address_objtyp
)
/
```

The LineItemList_ntab is a nested table.

Here is the create code for LineItemList_ntabtyp:

```
CREATE TYPE LineItem_objtyp AS OBJECT (
  LineItemNo NUMBER,
  Stock_ref REF StockItem_objtyp,
  Quantity NUMBER,
  Discount NUMBER
)
/

CREATE TYPE LineItemList_ntabtyp AS TABLE of LineItem_objtyp
/
```

Here is some insert code that does work:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT 1008, REF(C),
SYSDATE, '12-MAY-1999',
LineItemList_ntabtyp(),
NULL
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;
```

In the above code, the LineItemList_ntab is an empty LineItemList_ntabtyp. I am wanting to add values to this nested table rather than it being empty in the INSERT INTO code.

Here is some of the code I have tried to insert values with:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT 1008, REF(C),
SYSDATE, '12-MAY-1999',
LineItemList_ntabtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1) FROM Stock_objtab StckItem WHERE StckItem.StockNo = 1004,
NULL
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;

INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT 1008, REF(C),
SYSDATE, '12-MAY-1999',
INSERT INTO LineItemList_ntab SELECT 1, REF(StckItem),10,1 FROM Stock_objtab StckItem WHERE StckItem.StockNo = 1004, 
NULL
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;
```

The first insert statement above produces the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

The second insert statement above produces the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

May I please have some help to successfully insert values into the LineItemList_ntab nested table?

**UPDATE**

I have this code to insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT 
1008, 
REF(C),
SYSDATE, 
'12-MAY-1999',
(SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1)) FROM Stock_objtab StckItem WHERE StckItem.StockNo = 1004),
NULL
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;
```

I am now getting the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-22979: cannot INSERT object view REF or user-defined REF
>   22979. 00000 -  "cannot INSERT object view REF or user-defined REF"
>   *Cause:    Attempt to insert an object view REF or user-defined REF in a
>              REF column created to store system generated REF values"
>   *Action:   Make sure the REF to be inserted is not from an object view
>              or from a user-defined REF column

I am pretty sure that this error is because I may have created the table incorrectly, here is my table create code for the PurchaseOrder_objtab :

```
CREATE TABLE PurchaseOrder_objtab OF PurchaseOrder_objtyp(
PRIMARY KEY (PONo),
FOREIGN KEY (Cust_ref) REFERENCES Customer_objtab)
OBJECT ID PRIMARY KEY

  NESTED TABLE LineItemList_ntab STORE AS PoLine_ntab(
(PRIMARY KEY(NESTED_TABLE_ID, LineItemNo))
ORGANIZATION INDEX COMPRESS)
RETURN AS LOCATOR
/
```

Here is the code to create the nested table:

```
CREATE TYPE LineItemList_ntabtyp AS TABLE of LineItem_objtyp
/
```

**UPDATE2**

This code successfully adds information to the table:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT 1009, REF(C),
SYSDATE, '10-MAY-1999',
LineItemList_ntabtyp(),
NULL
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;
```

So the error has something to do with the LineItemList_ntabtyp.

Here is the table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE PurchaseOrder_objtab OF PurchaseOrder_objtyp(
PRIMARY KEY (PONo),
FOREIGN KEY (Cust_ref) REFERENCES Customer_objtab)
OBJECT ID PRIMARY KEY

NESTED TABLE LineItemList_ntab STORE AS PoLine_ntab((PRIMARY KEY(NESTED_TABLE_ID,LineItemNo)) ORGANIZATION INDEX COMPRESS) RETURN AS LOCATOR/
```

I am sure the error has something to do with the OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY for the above table.

**UPDATE3**

Thank you for the code. How about inserting more than one value into the nested table.

Your line of code for one item is:

```
(SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1)) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1004),
NULL)
```

How about if I would like to add two items, both StockNo 1004 and 1005? Is it something like this:

```
(SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1)) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1004) AND (SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(LineItem_objtyp(2, REF(StckItem), 10, 1)) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1005),
NULL)
```

**UPDATE4**

If, I add three items to the nested table, does the "FROM DUAL" statement stay as "FROM DUAL", or does it change to something reflecting three items? Also, does the "UNION ALL" statement appear as follows:

```
(
SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(
    SELECT LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1004         
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT LineItem_objtyp(2, REF(StckItem), 10, 1) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1005 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT LineItem_objtyp(3, REF(StckItem), 10, 1) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1006
)
FROM DUAL
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a type constructor in a select subquery to fill the nested table in your occasion:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT 
    1008, 
    REF(C),
    SYSDATE, 
    '12-MAY-1999',
    (SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1)) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1004),
    NULL
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not sure about the fact you're doing the task correctly (I mean it's useless to store object types as tables to my mind, I'd use managable ordinary tables instead of such archutecture.

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder_objtab
SELECT PurchaseOrder_objtyp(
    1008, 
    REF(C),
    SYSDATE, 
    '12-MAY-1999',
    (SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1)) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1004),
    NULL)
FROM Customer_objtab C 
WHERE C.CustNo = 1;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If you're eager to insert more than one value into the nested table, use enumeration (if the values are written by hand) or subquery:

```
(
    SELECT LineItemList_ntabtyp(
        SELECT LineItem_objtyp(1, REF(StckItem), 10, 1) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1004         
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT LineItem_objtyp(2, REF(StckItem), 10, 1) FROM Stock_objtab WHERE StockNo = 1005
    ) 
    FROM DUAL
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Can you please have a look at my OP update.

Comment: See my updated post, I STRONGLY recommend you to get rid of all these objects and use ordinary tables after all.. And make objects from data only on frontend-level, not in the database, it's not it's purposes.

Comment: Your code generates this error: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STCKITEM": invalid identifier. My update fixes this, yet the reference error occurs. Also, I NEED to use tables created from objects. It is in my brief to do so.

Comment: It means there's no column `StckItem` in `Customer_objtab`, suppose due to the fact the table `Customer_objtab` contains objects as well, not ordinary columns.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the Customer_obj table. Look at my update. The error has something to do with the LineItemList_ntabtyp.

Comment: Thank you for your code. Can you please have a look at my update about more than one StockItem?

Comment: Please have a look at Update4.

Comment: Yes, everything will be like you wrote.